# How can I test means equality of discrete and continuous random variable in python?

Tags: python, math, statistics, data-science

I have two random variables: X and Y. X variable (varies between 0 and 10) is continuous and Y is discrete (varies between 0 and 100). I wonder if I can make t-Test to check means equality of this two random variables? Also is there ready solutions in any statistical or mathematical python packages?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best option will be use of scipy. Exactly information about this we can find on the official website:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html

The only problem is that, the variables should be in array format. So you have to change X and Y into np.array.

In your case it will be working like:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind
X = np.array(X_list)
Y = np.array(Y_list) 

ttest_ind(X, Y)
```

And the result can look like this:

```
Ttest_indResult(statistic=0.26833823296238857, pvalue=0.788494433695651)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
As I can see, you're using two samples Students test for the means of two independent samples.
But I wonder if I can use it if one of my variable is discrete, but another is continuous?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know it should work properly even if one is discrete and another is continous :D